# Получить полную строку по соответствию началу в большом файле

Tags: python

Есть файл без расширения, в нем ~100 тыс. строк. Как быстро найти там нужную строку по соответствию началу?

Код:

```
string = "1. e2e4 e7e5 2."

with open("data", "r", encoding="utf-8) as file:
    for line in file.readlines():
        if line.startswith(string):
            ...
```

Этот код занимает много времени. Есть ли более быстрый способ?

Comment: `for line in file.readlines()` - достаточно `for line in file`.

Comment: Чтобы искало быстро, нужно заменить линейный поиск на какой-нибудь алгоритм ускоренного поиска. Например, отсортировать строки и искать бинарным поиском. Либо загрузить в базу данных, наложить индекс на колонку с текстом, и искать по этой колонке.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно структурировать данные, занести их в базу данных, затем запросом, можно быстро получать нужные данные.